# Gitlab CI ERROR: Job failed: exit code 52

Tags: node.js, gitlab, gitlab-ci

I have written the .gitlab-ci.yml file :

```
image: docker:latest
services:
  - docker:dind

stages:
- deploy_front_end

deploy_front_end:
  image: <<Some Curl Image >>
  stage: deploy_front_end
  only: 
  - master 
  tags:
  - docker
  - linux
  script:
  - echo "deploy_front_end Test"
  - curl -o /dev/null -s -w %{time_total}\\n  http://MachineName:6543/frontEndDeploy
```

I wanted this to hit the machine in the given port where a expressJS code is running which is :

```
const express = require('express')
const child_process = require('child_process');
const app = express()
const port = 6543

 app.route('/frontEndDeploy').get(  (req, res) => {
  child_process.exec('frontend.bat', function(error, stdout, stderr) {
      console.log(stderr);
      console.log(stdout);
      if(stderr || error) res.status(500).send(stderr || error);
      else res.send('frontend deployed successfully !!! '+ stdout);
  });
})

app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Example app listening on port ${port}!`))
```

And the frontend.bat is here :

```
cd C:\Users\yytcadm\Downloads\Front_End
for /f "tokens=5" %%a in ('netstat -aon ^| find ":3000" ^| find "LISTENING"') do taskkill /f /pid %%a
npm install && npm start
```

When the pipeline starts to run the Job fails and gives an error as:
[image]

The code runs successfully in the machine but the pipeline job fails and gives this error what do I have to do ? Please help me out !
Thank you!!!

Comment: it would help to have a bit more context on the command the job is running when it fails. Is it when it's running the curl command? it looks like it's trying to authenticate and failing, though I have to admit, I've never seen "exit code 52" before

Comment: Yeah ! When it runs the curl command , after some time it gives this error

Comment: curl: (52) Empty reply from server
Authenticating with credentials from job payload (GitLab Registry)
00:02
 ERROR: Job failed: exit code 52 .... This is the error I get